# How can I make an extension pop up at the push of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

can someone help me with my problem? I am trying to open an extension by clicking on a link (more precisely, it is the Metamask extension). But I do not know how to start there. When you click on it, the extension opens and you can log in with your Metamask data.  There you probably need the url of the extension, but I can't find it. I have now coded it so that I press on the link and you are redirected to the Metamask website, but that is not my goal.
I haven't found anything on the internet regarding this yet, so I'm hoping for some smart people who can help me out.
I would be happy to get some feedback.

Comment: Kindly share some code or detail. what are doing and how are you doing it!

Comment: So this is the html code I have done so far: <div class="image">
    <a href="https://metamask.io/" target="_blank"> 
        <img src="metamask.png" height="100" width="100">
        
          </a> 
</div>   And for the css stuff I have done this : .image{
float:right;
margin-top: -150px;
cursor: pointer; but how do I can link it to an extension and by a one click open the extension of metamask?